# Multi line Edit Text and first letter capitalization of Edit Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Hello I am trying to make `EditText` to multi line and first letter should be type as in capital which I am doing using `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` but after setting to input type to `textCapSentences` it set first letter in capital but  `EditText` is single line only. Can you please help me to make `EditText` to multiline plus first letter should be type in capital

Here it is current `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/commentsEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/comments"
    android:lines="5" />
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Have you try below code :-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/commentsEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/comments"
    android:lines="5" />
```

Comment: +1 yeah it worked thank you can you please update it to `android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"` so I can accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

Try to set `EditText` input type as below :

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/commentsEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/comments"
        android:lines="5"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
 edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);

and in xml
  android:inputType="textMultiLine"