# Android EditText MultiLine with Sentence Caps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, ime

I am trying to instantiate an **EditText** with mutli-line capability as well as the first character capitalization flag, like so:

```
myEditText?.setSingleLine(false)
myEditText?.inputType =
  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or
  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES or
  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE
  myEditText?.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)
```

I've also tried combining the flags with the *plus* instead of *or*:

```
myEditText?.setSingleLine(false)
myEditText?.inputType =
  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT +
  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES +
  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE
  myEditText?.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)
```

But, for some reason, I could only get multi-line or first-character capitalization, but not both. The result is either a **keyboard with no return key**, or a **return key that just adds spaces to the same line**.

Am I missing a flag, or perhaps using the worng ones?

---

**EDIT:** *I forgot to mention that my UI is purely built by code with no XML layout file.*

Comment: Did you try this ?-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651166/multi-line-edit-text-and-first-letter-capitalization-of-edit-text

Comment: Any specific reason to not use xml for ui?

Comment: @PrajwalW No. But that's the project structure.

Comment: @PrajwalW Why do you keep deleting your posts? And along with them other people's comments as well? Bad form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently, I found out that when we set `inputType`, it will override `singleLine` settings.

1. Set input type.
2. Set single line = false.

--

```
editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES
editText.setSingleLine(false)
```

I am not setting imeOptions. This seems to work well.

This seems to work on Emulator and Google Pixel 3xl.

Comment: Thank you. Finally a combination that works. Somehow, I think that the order of execution makes a difference. Pushing the `setSingleLine()` after the `inputype` did the trick.

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble getting CAP_SENTENCE and multiline via code only and this worked!